# How to stop a post from publishing if the file upload is not a image/gif

Tags: images, uploads

This is the code and i want to stop the post publishing if the file is not an image
Is this possible ?

```
case "window-image":
        $format = 'image';
        $title = esc_html($_POST['title_image']);
        $tags = $_POST['tags_image'];
        $comments = isset($_POST['comments_image']) ? 1 : 0;
        $anonymous = isset($_POST['anonymous_image']) ? 1 : 0;
        $comment_status = $comments == 1 ? 'open' : 'closed';
        $user_id = $id;

        if(($_FILES['image_imagepost']['error'] != 0 && $image == '') || $title == '') {
            wp_redirect(home_url('/') . '?posterror=1');
            exit; 
        }       

        $post = array(
          'comment_status' => $comment_status,
          'ping_status'    => 'open',
          'post_author'    => $user_id,
          'post_content'   => '',
          'post_status'    => $status,
          'post_title'     => $title,
          'post_type'      => 'post',
         );  
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);

#Create attachment
    if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    }
        $upload = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['file']['name'], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) );
        $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $upload['file'] ), null );
        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $attachment = array(
            'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['baseurl'] . _wp_relative_upload_path( $upload['file'] ),
            'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $upload['file'] )),    
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_author' => $user_id,
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload['file'], $post_id );
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload['file'] );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
#Create attachment

#Use attachment
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );
#Use attachment


        $nsfw = isset($_POST['nsfw_image']) ? 1 : 2;
        add_post_meta($post_id, '_standard_nsfw', $nsfw);
        add_post_meta($post_id, '_anonymous', $anonymous);

        break;
```

Comment: Is this using the `save_post` hook by chance?

Comment: No, i don't think so .. I think i need something like this :  if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
   && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
   echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
   wp_trash_post( $post_id  );
   }  but i think the code is wrong because he keeps giving me same message for every file

Comment: What hook are you using for the above code or, how are you implementing this code?

Comment: i don't know know for sure what you mean i'm beginner to wordpress but look here :  http://textuploader.com/5v817

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I managed to work .
I put this code  into upload code

```
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    wp_trash_post( $post_id  );
}
```

And this allow users to post just images and if he upload another file type get a message and the post is automaticaly going to trash.